Fontconfig head is null exception when running AWS Lambda
I am working on creating a Lambda function that uses Spring Boot. When the API is invoked, the application makes some API calls and creates an image containing some text, generated using Java Graphics2D.
When I run the application as a Spring Boot application and make a request, it generates and displays the image using fonts I have available on my PC.
When I run the application using sam local start-api to test it as a Lambda and make the same request, an exception occurs:
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fontconfig head is null, check your fonts or fonts configuration
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.getVersion(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.readFontConfigFile(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.init(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11FontManager.createFontConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager$2.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager$2.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FcFontManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11FontManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.PlatformFontInfo.createFontManager(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.getFont2D(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Font$FontAccessImpl.getFont2D(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.FontUtilities.getFont2D(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.checkFontInfo(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.getFontInfo(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/sun.java2d.pipe.GlyphListPipe.drawString(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/sun.java2d.pipe.ValidatePipe.drawString(Unknown Source)
        at java.desktop/sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawString(Unknown Source)
        at com.mewhorter.timebyfive.service.CollageService.drawCollage(CollageService.java:120)
        at com.mewhorter.timebyfive.service.CollageService.collage(CollageService.java:75)
        at com.mewhorter.timebyfive.controller.CollageController.collage(CollageController.java:55)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)

If I understand correctly, this is due to there being no available fonts in the container my application is running in. I want to use any monospaced font. To work around this I've tried:

Not setting the font at all
Setting the font to "Monospaced" graphics.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.BOLD, (int) (LABEL_FONT_SIZE_PX * .75)));
Attempting to package "Source Code Pro" with my Lambda function by making these changes (following this StackOverflow question):

Setting the font:
graphics.setFont(new Font("Source Code Pro", Font.BOLD, (int) (LABEL_FONT_SIZE_PX * .75)));

Creating a fonts directory in the project root:
- fonts
  - Source_Code_Pro
    - SourceCodePro-VariableFont_wght.ttf
    - SourceCodePro-Italic-VariableFont_wght.ttf
  - fonts.conf

fonts.conf:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <dir>/var/task/fonts/</dir>
  <cachedir>/tmp/fonts-cache/</cachedir>
  <config></config>
</fontconfig>

In template.yaml:
Resources:
  TimeByFiveFunction:
    Properties:
      Environment:
        Variables:
          FONTCONFIG_PATH: "/var/task/fonts"

I've observed the same exception trying all three of these options. I have these questions:

What is the proper way to install a custom font on an AWS Lambda function?
Any monospaced font will do. Do I need to install one or would there be a default one installed in the container?

